# command 'imp' not found while import dmp file

Tags: oracle

I installed oracle enterprise edition 11g on aws. And I couldn't transfer dmp file into the location that I want to send, so I ended up placing under /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/.  I know it is very strange to put there but it worked. and using putty, I tried to import dmp file that I just placed under /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps. The command was like this. imp userid=scott/tiger fromuser=scott touser=tiger file='scott.dmp'
 and I got the following message: Would you please help me with this? Thank you in advance!

```
Command 'imp' not found, did you mean:

  command 'gimp' from snap gimp (2.10.12)
  command 'icp' from deb renameutils
  command 'ifp' from deb ifp-line-libifp
  command 'ip' from deb iproute2
  command 'cmp' from deb diffutils
  command 'omp' from deb openvas-cli
  command 'xmp' from deb xmp
  command 'imc' from deb italc-management-console
  command 'gimp' from deb gimp
  command 'iep' from deb emboss
  command 'imv' from deb renameutils
  command 'bmp' from deb ztex-bmp
  command 'imgp' from deb imgp

See 'snap info <snapname>' for additional versions.
```

Comment: Most likely, your Oracle Home isn't in your path.  Either specify the full path to the imp executable or update your PATH environment variable to include that directory.

Comment: Thank  you for your reply! but I ended up transferring data using oracle sql developer. Thank you for your help though:)